# How to create View Composer for view in subdirectory in PHP Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I am trying to create a [View Composer](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/views#view-composers) in PHP Laravel 5. I have organized my template layouts like this

```
resources/
  views/
     layouts/
       master2.blade.php
     index.blade.php
     master1.blade.php
```

I have already successfully register a composer for master1 by calling

```
view()->composer('master1', function ($view) { });
```

but, how to create one for master2 ?

I have tried both:

```
view()->composer('layouts.master1', function ($view) { });
view()->composer('layouts/master1', function ($view) { });
```

but none of them work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure it out. The following syntax works:

```
view()->composer('layouts.master1', function ($view) { });
```

but first I have to clear the artisan cache and make a edit in view (like insert a space):

```
php artisan clear-compiled
php artisan cache:clear
```